# arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,["SHAPE@"]) has no firstPoint object

Tags: arcpy

I am having trouble getting the start and end point of a line using the code below.

```
import arcpy

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Lines",["Material","SHAPE@"]) as curs:
    for row in curs:
        startptx = row[1].firstPoint.X
        startpty = row[1].firstPoint.Y
```

The error I get is as followed:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'firstPoint'

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1

Answer (score 7):

The problem was that I had null values. Make sure to check your data for null/nil values!

```
if row[1]:
    startptx = row[1].firstPoint.X
else:
    print "There are null values in your data"
```